# How to replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform and migrate to navigator.userAgentData

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, navigator

I am attempting to access an Elastic cluster but have been greeted with the following error:

"Please upgrade your browser. This Elastic installation has strict security requirements enabled that your current browser does not meet."

When I open the Console and check Issues, here is what I'm seeing:

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A6cX.png)

"A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.

To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData."

How do I migrate to navigator.userAgentData? I would like to try this as my next troubleshooting step, but if you happen to have experience with Elastic or have resolved this error/issue before, would love to hear how you did it.

I have tried accessing this Elastic cluster in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and Chromium - the issue persists across all these browsers.

I have tried updating my browser, Chrome is up to date and running Version 114.0.5735.134 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have tried different user agents in Chrome.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Chrome

I have tried turning on and off all the CSP settings in Firefox just in case this csp value is part of the problem, which didn't resolve the issue

[Elements script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW3DQ.png)

Comment: This issue has been resolved, it appears there was an issue with my group policy object and a group policy updated has resolved this issue

Comment: If it's resolved, then please post the answer and close the question~

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov not seeing how I can close the question without deleting it. Unfortunately it appears i'm limited as i'm using a new account and the close link under tags is only for users with 250+ reputation points.

Comment: You just post the answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved, it appears there was an issue with my group policy object and a group policy updated has resolved this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).